# Why does the homrebrew formula test fail with a serde_json error "expected value at line 1 column 1"

Tags: rust, homebrew

I have a rust lib that I compile with cargo and the resulting binary should bundle a folder of json files. Those json files are read by my program via:

```rust
let filename = "./fonts/console.json";
let data = read_to_string(Path::new(filename).as_os_str())
    .unwrap_or(format!("Unable to read file \"{}\"", color(filename, Colors::Red)));
serde_json::from_str(&data).unwrap_or_else(|error| {
    panic!(
        "JSON parsing error encountered for: \"{}\"\nError: {}",
        color(filename, Colors::Red),
        color(&format!("{}", error), Colors::Yellow)
    )
})
```

When I run `cargo build --release` I get a binary that I run with like this:

```bash
λ my_thing test


test
```

And the code path for the rust code above is triggered without any errors.
I also like to add that `cargo install mything` works as expected as well. No issues which makes me think this is not a cargo bundle compile issue...?!

Now I'm trying to publish this lib on homebrew so I wrote this formula:

```rb
class Mything < Formula
  desc "Description etc"
  homepage "https://hpomepage.com"
  url "https://github.com/path/to/archive/refs/tags/v3.0.0.tar.gz"
  sha256 "547a8e3059e1543debd8e0f10e9efd05c27d13b0717echs7634e1c4cf49d44cb"
  license "GPL-3.0-or-later"

  depends_on "rust" => :build

  def install
    chdir "rust" do
      system "make"
      system "cargo", "build", "--release", "--bin", "mything"
      bin.install "target/release/mything"
    end
  end

  test do
    print "#{bin}/mything test -f console\n"
    # ^-- I added this for debugging to make 100% sure I'm not getting the binaries mixed up
    assert_match "\n\n\ntest\n\n\n",
      shell_output("#{bin}/mything test -f console")
  end
end
```

Installing this works fine but when I run `brew test mything` I get:

```bash
λ brew test mything
==> Testing mything
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mything/3.0.0/bin/mything test -f console
==> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mything/3.0.0/bin/mything test -f console
thread 'main' panicked at 'JSON parsing error encountered for: "./fonts/console.json"
Error: expected value at line 1 column 1', src/font.rs:88:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Error: mything: failed
An exception occurred within a child process:
  Minitest::Assertion: Expected: 0
  Actual: 101
/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.15.0/lib/minitest/assertions.rb:183:in `assert'
/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.15.0/lib/minitest/assertions.rb:218:in `assert_equal'
/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_assertions.rb:26:in `shell_output'
/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/mything.rb:21:in `block in <class:Mything>'
/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:2112:in `block (3 levels) in run_test'
/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb:595:in `with_env'
/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:2111:in `block (2 levels) in run_test'
/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:948:in `with_logging'
/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:2110:in `block in run_test'
/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/mktemp.rb:63:in `block in run'
/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/mktemp.rb:63:in `chdir'
/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/mktemp.rb:63:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:2363:in `mktemp'
/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:2104:in `run_test'
/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/test.rb:43:in `block in <main>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/timeout.rb:93:in `block in timeout'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/timeout.rb:33:in `block in catch'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/timeout.rb:33:in `catch'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/timeout.rb:33:in `catch'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/timeout.rb:108:in `timeout'
/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/test.rb:48:in `<main>'
```

Now I copy the printed first line of that output and run it the same way:

```bash
λ /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mything/3.0.0/bin/mything test -f console


test
```

And it works. That's the very same binary that brew is testing here.

I don't know much ruby so there is a good chance I'm getting the test wrong somehow?
I also tried to do this in the test:

```rb
system bin/"cfonts", "test", "-f", "console"
```

Which also fails with the same error.

When I run that binary now since it's installed via brew and in my `PATH` it all works as well which is nuts...

```bash
λ mything test -f console


test


λ which mything
/opt/homebrew/bin/mything
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you are opening a relative path: `./fonts/console.json`. In your test function, could you perhaps print the working directory to stderr, and double-check the contents of the file in `fonts/console.json` relative to that working directory?

Comment: The relative path is definitely the issue. I found that I can embed the contents of the json files via [`include_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_str.html) so doing that now and posting an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that of course the relative path was only working in certain directories where that folder was present.
A rust issue after-all.

So I used the [`include_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_str.html) macro to include the contents of the json file into the binary at compile time:

```rust
let font_content = include_str!("../fonts/console.json");

serde_json::from_str(&font_content).unwrap_or_else(|error| {
    panic!(
        "JSON parsing error encountered for: \"{}\"\nError: {}",
        color(filename, Colors::Red),
        color(&format!("{}", error), Colors::Yellow)
    )
})
```

Now the brew formula works fine:

```rb
class Mything < Formula
  desc "Description etc"
  homepage "https://hpomepage.com"
  url "https://github.com/path/to/archive/refs/tags/v3.0.0.tar.gz"
  sha256 "547a8e3059e1543debd8e0f10e9efd05c27d13b0717echs7634e1c4cf49d44cb"
  license "GPL-3.0-or-later"

  depends_on "rust" => :build

  def install
    chdir "rust" do
      system "make"
      system "cargo", "build", "--release", "--bin", "mything"
      bin.install "target/release/mything"
    end
  end

  test do
    assert_match "\n\n\ntest\n\n\n",
      shell_output("#{bin}/mything test -f console")
  end
end
```

```bash
λ brew test cfonts
==> Testing cfonts
==> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mything/3.0.0/bin/mything test -f console
```